# How to use react native VirtualizedList to iterate over data object?

Tags: android, listview, react-native, react-native-listview

I am successfully able to migrate from ListView to FlatList when the data is an Array, but how to implement the new React Native List types for Objects as data?

I am trying to use VirtualizedList (link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/virtualizedlist.html#virtualizedlist) but can't get it to iterate over all the keys.

Example data:

```
{
   ruth: {
      id: 10901,
      fullName: 'Ruth Rachelin'
      gender: 'female'
    },
   rupert: {
      id: 20033,
      fullName: 'Rupert Luis'
      gender: 'male'
   }
}
```

Code, not quite right:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { VirtualizedList } from 'react-native';
import _isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import _size from 'lodash/size';
import _forEach from 'lodash/forEach';
import GameListView from './GameListView';

export default class GameCategoriesRoll extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        // console.log('data:', this.props.data);
        this._getItem = this._getItem.bind(this)
        this._keyExtractor = this._keyExtractor.bind(this)
        this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this)
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext)
    {
        return !_isEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !_isEqual(this.state, nextState)
    }

    _keyExtractor(data) {
       // returns all keys in object
        return _forEach(data, function(category, key){
            console.log('keyextractor:', key);
            return key
        });
    }

    _getItem(data) {
      // data is the whole collection returned so i try to return just one key
        return _forEach(data, function(category, key){
            console.log('getItem category: ', category, 'key', key);
            return category
        });
    }

    _renderRow(item)
    {
        console.log('renderRow: ', item); // <- returns whole collection / object
        if (item.appItems && item.appItems.length > 0)
        {
            console.log('item', item);
            /*return (
                <GameListView
                    category={item.name}
                    games={item}
                    recentlyPlayed={false}
                />)*/
        }
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <VirtualizedList
                keyExtractor={(item) => this._keyExtractor(item)}
                data={this.props.data}
                getItem={(data) => this._getItem(data)}
                getItemCount={(data) => data ? _size(data) : 0}
                renderItem={this._renderRow}
                debug
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, overflow: 'hidden' }}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                removeClippedSubviews={false}
                enableEmptySections={true}
            />
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: Give us the code you wrote to iterate... because iterating trough an object is different than iterating trough an array.

Comment: @WilomGfx Okay I updated it with my code, but it's not quite right. It doesn't iterate through the data object.

Answer (score 0):

I got around it! I converted the object to an array by using lodash's `_values()` 
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values

So this does the trick:

```
<FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
    data={_values(this.props.data)}
    renderItem={this._renderRow}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, overflow: 'hidden' }}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    enableEmptySections={true}
/>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. But this workaround isn't working for me. I have a huge JSON object as data. do you know any other way ?